# Can't get double parameter in node (C++)

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, roscpp, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file with:

```
  <arg name="INTENSITY" default="1.2" />
  <param name="my_intensity" type="double" value="$(arg INTENSITY)" />
```

The same launch file starts a ROS node, *my_node* . In *my_node*'s main method I have the following, to get that parameter:

```
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  string param_name;
  if(!nh.searchParam("/my_intensity", param_name) ){
    ROS_ERROR("Can't find param.");
    return -1;
  }

  double it;
  ros::param::get(param_name, it);  

  ROS_INFO("Intensity is %f.", it);
  ...
```

Running this prints `Intensity is 0.0.`. Although when I run `rosparam get /my_intensity` in a terminal window I get the correct value (1.2).

When I change the type of `it` to string, what I get is an empty string. The same approach always worked for my other nodes. So I am really confused. What may be causing this behavior?

Thank you.

System: Ubuntu 16.04, ros-kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306273/can%27t-get-double-parameter-in-node-(c++)/) by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2018-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-19**:
Please add the bit from your launch file where you start your node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I found the reason after poking some more. The same node was subscribing to a topic with the same name (my_intensity). Also, the topic name was remapped to another name in node launch. I used a separate name for the parameter and topic name to solve it.

---

Originally posted by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) with karma: 78 on 2018-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0